# TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Member' discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am having a problem with the report command I am working on. Whenever I run the command on my discord server, the error "TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Member'" comes up. If anyone knows how to solve this problem can you tell me? Thank you for taking your time to read this.

```
# bot.py
from discord import Member
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = ''

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message, Member):

    Member = discord.Member(Member)

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$report ', Member.mention):
        Sends = 'That user has been reported!'
        await message.channel.send(Sends)

client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 3):

I can see that your new to discord.py. First of all, the on_message function does not take member. It only takes message. When you add an event to your code you always want to check the [Event Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference) and check the paramters for that event. You cannot add or remove paramaters. For this case your code would start like this

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message)
```

To get the member you would use:

```
member = message.author
```

Also I recommend you use commands

```
from discord.ext import commands
```

It will be a lot easier and you can add your own paramaters. I've made an example of what you're doing with your on_message function in a command

```
@client.command
async def report(ctx, member : discord.Member, reason=None)
    await ctx.send(f"Reported {member.mention} for {reason}")
```

Also remember if you have an on_message function your commands wont work unless you use bot.process_commands at the end. Read the FAQ on how to do that. Heres the link:
**Why does on_message make my commands stop working?**
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Comment: When I import commands then do the `@client.command` I get an error saying "'Client' object has no attribute 'command'"